# OOP: Bounds of a variable's scope

Tags: oop, variables, scope, computer-science, principal

Consider the following java code:

```
public class Main() {                           //Line 1
    public static void main(String[] args) {    //Line 2
        System.out.println("Hello World.");     //Line 3
                                                //Line 4
        int c = 10;                             //Line 5
        System.out.println(c);                  //Line 6
    }                                           //Line 7
}                                               //Loin 8
```

On what lines does the scope of variable c exist? Lines 2-7 or Lines 5-6?

This poses the question of whether or not a variable scope can precede the variable's declaration itself. Potentially, one can define scope as the area of code in which a variable can be used (Lines 5-6).

But this also raises the questions of whether scope is defined generically for all the variable's in a section of code (basically scope being defined by brackets) or if it's defined for each variable independently?

What's the proper interpretation of scope, and what's the justification for that interpretation?

Comment: 5 to 6. The scope starts with the variable declaration. If you declare it in a function/method, it is only visible within this function/method. If you declare it in the class, it is availabe from each class member (function/method in this class). For a class wide variable also google for `public`, `protected` and `private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable scope defines parts of code where a variable can be accessed. Java has a few different scopes. The one you're asking about is `local variable block scope`. Java has other scopes like `class scope`.

Also [Java Language Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2).

> Every declaration that introduces a name has a scope (§6.3), which is the part of the program text within which the declared entity can be referred to by a simple name.

So it's not only about variables. Classes also are subject to this (e.g. are `inner classes`).

As for your specific questions.

> scope is defined generically for all the variable's in a section of code (basically scope being defined by brackets)

**no**, but

- variables defined in some brackets are not visible outside
- you can not define two variables with the same name inside of brackets

> defined for each variable independently

**yes** each own variable not being visible to the code before its definition, so each of the scopes differ

> On what lines does the scope of variable c exist? Lines 2-7 or Lines 5-6?

It's 5-6. If you'll write something like `System.out.println(c)` in line 3, the compiler will show you an error.